# Maintain active row after insertRows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to keep the selection on the original active row after insertRows has been used in an onEdit function?

```
function onEdit(e) {
    [snip]
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertRows(3, 3);
}
```

I want to be able to leave the cell I was editing, have the onEdit() fire but I get to keep typing in the next cell, and any subsequent cells, of the row that I was working in.

If I tab out of the cell that has the onEdit() function whatever I type in the next cell will be on the same row as the cell I left.  The next time I tab, however (if the onEdit() has finished), I will be put back to spreadsheet row I was on before the insertRows() function was called.

I'd like to be able to continue on the new spreadsheet row (which is the data row I was working on), regardless of how long the onEdit() may take to run.

In this image [screen shot](http://www.dublinyouthultimate.com/Untitled-1.png),  I was working on row 13 when the onEdit() was call.  New rows 13-16 were added by insertRows().  I was able to tab out and enter yes and yes beside number 15 on row 17, then the onEdit() finished and the next cell I typed in was back on row 13.  I am looking for a way to be able to continue tabbing across and have the selected cell be the one I have coloured purple instead of the one highlighted in blue.

Answer (score 1):

This should be good enough if you are editing the spreadsheet slowly (reasonable pace). However, it'll break if you type in things at like 120wpm. I hope this will be helpful to you.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  [snip]
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  sheet.insertRows(3, 3);
  //gets the current cell
  const curCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  const curColumn = curCell.getColumn();
  const curRow = curCell.getRow();
  //shift the row down by numRowsInserted and col by 1 because you tabbed away
  sheet.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(curRow+3, curColumn+1));
  
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.  The next field is potentially just a checkbox I (users) could be out of it real quick and your suggestion would jump them back to a cell they've already left.  Thanks for the idea though.